# Getting current hub in SignalR

Tags: signalr

Is there a good way to call methods in SignalR hub from a controller ?

Right now I have this:

```
public class StatsHub : Hub
{
    private static readonly Lazy<StatsHub> instance = new Lazy<StatsHub>(() => new StatsHub());
    public static StatsHub Instance { get { return instance.Value; } }

    public StatsHub()
    {
        if (this.Clients == null)
        {
            var hubContext = SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StatsHub>();
            this.Clients = hubContext.Clients;
            this.Groups = hubContext.Groups;
        }
    }

    // methods here...
}
```

so in my controller actions I can just say, for example

```
StatsHub.Instance.SendMessage("blah");
```

and it's almost good, except that hubContext doesn't have Caller or Context properties of Hub - which are nice to have.

Hopefully, there's a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found a DefaultHubManager, which is what I need, I think.

```
DefaultHubManager hd = new DefaultHubManager(GlobalHost.DependencyResolver);
var hub = hd.ResolveHub("AdminHub") as AdminHub;
hub.SendMessage("woohoo");
```

Works. If there's an even better/preferred way - please share.

Comment: This works no more (in SignalR 2?). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896739/use-hub-methods-from-controller .

Comment: `DefaultHubManager` exists in SignalR 2.x however `hub.Context` is null, so all operations fail.

Comment: this works in signalR 2.0 but i get an exception Using a Hub instance not created by the HubPipeline is unsupported

Answer (score 18):

If you want to broadcast over a hub from outside of the hub, you need `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>()` to get ahold of the hub context. You can then use this context to broadcast via the `.Clients` property.

As indicated in your sample code you already get ahold of the hub context, but doing so inside the hub just doesn't feel right in my opinion. If you're only using the logic in `SendMessage()` from your controller actions, I'd move the code right into the controller action and use the hub context obtained via `GetHubContext<T>()` from there.

Please note that the `Caller` or `Context` property will always be `null` in this scenario, because SignalR wasn't involved when making a request to the server and therefore cannot provide the properties.

Answer (score 2):

As per the latest documentation, IHubContext can be injected by dependency injection.

documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0

In service you could do

```
public class NotificationService : INotificationService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;

    public NotificationService(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }
}
```

In controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;

    public HomeController(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }
}
```

Once you have HubContext you could send message to group/client etc.

```
public async Task SendMessage()
{
    return await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Notify", $"Hello world");
}
```